# How to assign an image of transformed UIImageview to some other UIImageview?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, cgaffinetransform

In my application I am applying different kinds of transformations like rotate left,rotate right,flip verticle,flip horizontal to a `UIImageview`. After applying these operations the position of the `UIImageview` changes. I want this changed image to be assigned to some other view, not the original image. When I am assigning `imageview.image` to the other view it's assigning the original image. How can I rectify this?

As suggested by David.I am applying following code for left rotation

```
//rotation left;
        int x1=ivPhoto.frame.origin.x;
        int y1=ivPhoto.frame.origin.y;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(ivPhoto.image.size);


        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees2));        

        CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), transform);
         [ivPhoto.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(x1,y1,ivPhoto.frame.size.width, ivPhoto.frame.size.height)];

        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        ivPhoto.image=newImage;
```

But i am not getting rotated image.the image is in original position

Answer (score 0):

After your transformation finishes capture newer image like this:

```
CGSize fittingSize = yourImgView.frame.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(fittingSize);
[yourImgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImahe *capImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now assign these capImage to another UIImageView with transformed image

Answer (score 0):

You should make your changes in a context and save it to a UIImage when you're done. Then set that image in the imageview:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sizeOfImage);


    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

etc etc

```
    CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), transform);
[imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(position.x, position.y, size.width, size.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```